# Recuperar valor via $_POST y cambiar valor

Tags: php

Tengo una variable que recupero mediante $_POST donde esta puede contener "On" o "Off" y mediante un botón, al hacer onclick quiero que cambie el estado.

Como puedo añadir las siguientes lineas para poder controlar dicha casuística cuando hago el onclick?

```
$stat = ($_POST['status'] == "On" ? "On" : "Off");

$stat = ($_POST['status'] == "Off" ? "Off" : "On");
```

Una vez tengo el valor detectado, lo actualizaría de la siguiente forma en lo quiero actualizar en BBDD al valor contrario

```
$query = "UPDATE `status` SET `status` = '$stat'  WHERE `id` = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con una peticion ajax y tus archivos aparte, o puedes hacerlo con un formulario recargando la pagina. 
solo necesitas la primer linea

```
$stat = ($_POST['status'] == "On" ? "On" : "Off");
```

la segunda es redundante.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con un ajax asi:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
let i = 0;

document.getElementById("switch").addEventListener('click', function(){
 
i++;

let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
let form = new FormData();

 if(i%2 == 0){
    console.log('off');
  form.append('status','off');
 }else{
    console.log('on');
  form.append('status','on');
 }

http.onreadystatechange = function(){
 if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
 console.log(http.responseText);
 }
}

http.open('POST','url',true);
http.send(form);


});


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<body>

<button id="switch">switch</button>

<body>
<html>
```

En

```
console.log(http.responseText);
```

Es la respuesta del php en donde en el archivo php puedes poner el fragmento de codigo:

```
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
```

En la parte del JavaScript

```
http.open('POST','url',true);
```

Donde dice 'url' pones la ruta o direccion de tu archivo php al que quieres setear el $_POST

Que puedes confirmar que en el post, en la propiedad 'status' por cada click que le haces a tu boton va a cambiar el valor en 'on' y 'off' sin recargar la pagina.